# Im trying to have multiple lines of imput, and store the strings, integers into three seperate variables

Tags: java, arrays

So, I'm trying to store multiple lines of code and add each input up under its certain array. So basically, a person enters the name of the game, this gets stored into an array called 'game', then they enter on that same line the score they have achieved and that's should be stored into aray 'score' and the same for the minutes played. You get my drift.

the input should be as followed...

```
<name of player> 
<game name> : <score> : <min played>
```

The data should be split at the delimiter ":".... 
However, my problem is that my code does not add each part of the user input and only stores the first line and does not go onto the next line. The code I have is beneath. I would highly appreciate any advice I can get. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Report {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        String gameName;
        int gameScore;
        int minPlayed;
        String[] game = new String[100];
        int[] score = new int[100];
        int[] min = new int[100];

        String[] name1 = new String[100];
        int nextLine = 0;


        System.out.println("Can you enter your name, game, achievement score, and time played in the following format as shown below:");
        System.out.println("<NAME>");
        System.out.println("<GAME> : <SCORE> : <TIMEPLAYED>");
        System.out.println("Once you have finished your input please notify the program you have finished with the command 'quit':");

        for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // initialise Scanner
            name = keyboard.nextLine(); // assign next line of input to name

           if (name.compareToIgnoreCase("quit") == 0) {
              break;
            }
            name1[index] = name;
            nextLine = nextLine + 1;

            String input = keyboard.nextLine(); // next line of input
            String[] variables = input.split(":"); // perform split
            if (variables.length != 3) {
                // handle invalid input here
            }
            game[index] = variables[0].trim(); // first token trimmed of whitespaces
            try {
                score[index] = Integer.parseInt(variables[1].trim()); // parse second token as int
                min[index] = Integer.parseInt(variables[2].trim()); // parse third token as int
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // handle invalid input here
            }
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < nextLine; index++) {

            System.out.println("Players name: " + name1[index]);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Total games: " + game[index]);
            System.out.println("Overall score: " + score[index]);
            System.out.println("Total minutes played: " + min[index]);

            System.out.println(game[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my typical ouptput should look like...

```
PLayers Name: ......
Number of games: 12
Total Score: 467
Total minutes played: 1045
```

This is what it actually looks like....

```
PLayers Name: Matty
Number of games: GTA IV
Total Score: 12
Total minutes played: 124
```

As you can see it basically only splits the first line and puts it into these headings when I want it to add each part up and put them like in the the actuall output I want. It only splits the first games data and does not add it up with the other lines beneath it.

Here it is my pseudo code....

```
get name of player and store in a variable
loop for 100
    get input
    if it is "quit" then break
    split up input
    if I don't get 3 things then it is invalid 
    else if I do get 3 things
        store the first one in an array for game names
        store the second one in an array for scores
        store the third one in an array for times
        if I can’t convert scores &/or times - it is invalid
end loop

output player’s name
output a line of “------------------------”
loop for how many valid games we have
    output a line containing gamename, score, minutes played
end loop
```

Then add all the games up and change into a int for the final output as shown above, then do the same with all the scores and minutes and print out as shown above...

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) or [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: I tried scanner but I was told by my lecturer that I should not use that

Comment: Well, since you're splitting the `String` on `:`, you have the basic input requirements. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Now that we know the typical output, what does your **actual** output look like?

Comment: You want allow user to input many players name and many games for each?

Comment: Basically... With the program I need each line to be split up, there can be any between 100.... Each line needs to be split at ":", which works and then the name of the game on each line all needs to be stored in the same array called "game", hen the second part of the line which is the score needs to be stored in array "score" ad the same with the minutes played but stored in an array called "min". However, my program at the moment only stores the first line and prints out the name of the game for number of games, and the score for that game on total score and theminutes played also, when it

Comment: and no. I want there to be one players name, but many games with the corresponding data on each separate line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i understand properly, but do you whant something like this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Report
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String name;

        String[] game = new String[100];
        int[] score = new int[100];
        int[] min = new int[100];

        int nextLine = 0;

        System.out.println("Can you enter your name, game, achievement score, and time played in the following format as shown below:");
        System.out.println("<NAME>");
        System.out.println("<GAME> : <SCORE> : <TIMEPLAYED>");
        System.out.println("Once you have finished your input please notify the program you have finished with the command 'quit':");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // initialise Scanner
        name = keyboard.nextLine(); // assign next line of input to name

        for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++)
        {
            String input = keyboard.nextLine(); // next line of input

            if (input.compareToIgnoreCase("quit") == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            nextLine = nextLine + 1;

            String[] variables = input.split(":"); // perform split
            if (variables.length != 3)
            {
                // handle invalid input here
            }
            game[index] = variables[0].trim(); // first token trimmed of whitespaces
            try
            {
                score[index] = Integer.parseInt(variables[1].trim()); // parse second token as int
                min[index] = Integer.parseInt(variables[2].trim()); // parse third token as int
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                // handle invalid input here
            }
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < nextLine; index++)
        {

            System.out.println("Players name: " + name);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Total games: " + game[index]);
            System.out.println("Overall score: " + score[index]);
            System.out.println("Total minutes played: " + min[index]);

            System.out.println(game[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bercik I LOVE YOU! that is basically what I want for the first bit. Then I want it to add all of the data up so it has an overall amount for each, amount of games, score and tome played

Comment: To do this loop around every element in your for example scores array, parse it to integer (cause it is string) and sum to some variable for example scoresSum

Comment: So how can I calculate the number of game names entered and change it into an integer to then output